# find and replace within file

Tags: regex, perl, replace, sed, awk

I have a requirement to search for a pattern which is something like :

```
timeouts = {default = 3.0; };
```

and replace it with

```
timeouts = {default = 3000.0;.... };
```

i.e multiply the timeout by factor of 1000.

Is there any way to do this for all files in a directory

```
EDIT :
```

Please note that some of the files are symlinks in the directory.Is there any way to get this done for symlinks also ?

Please note that timeouts exists as a substring also in the files  so i want to make sure that only this line gets replaced. Any solution is acceptable  using sed awk perl .

Comment: -1: what have you tried? what doesn't work?

Comment: Some of the files in directory are symlinks. How can we do this for links

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
for f in *
do
    sed -i 's/\(timeouts = {default = [0-9]\+\)\(\.[0-9]\+;\)\( };\)/\1000\2....\3/' "$f" 
done
```

It will make the replacements in place for each file in the current directory. Some versions of `sed` require a backup extension after the `-i` option. You can supply one like this:

```
sed -i .bak ...
```

Some versions don't support in-place editing. You can do this:

```
sed '...' "$f" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$f"
```

Note that this is obviously not actually multiplying by 1000, so if the number is `3.1` it would become "3000.1" instead of `3100.0`.

Comment: I think the '....'s could be any text such as other timeouts. Not literally '....'s.

Comment: @dogbane: Possibly, but it wasn't present in the before and it was in the after.

Comment: actually some of the files in directory are symlinks. How can we do this for links ?

Comment: @TopCoder: `sed -i '...' "$(readlink -e "$f")"` or `sed '...' "$f" > tmpfile && mv tmpfile "$(readlink -e "$f")"`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ perl -pi.bak -e 's/\w+\s*=\s*{\s*\w+\s*=\s*\K(-?[0-9.]+)/sprintf "%0.1f", 1000 * $1/eg' *
```

Notes:

- The regex matches just the number (see `\K` in perlre)
- The `/e` means the replacement is evaluated
- I include a `sprintf` in the replacement just in case you need finer control over the formatting
- Perl's `-i` can operate on a bunch of files

**EDIT**

It has been pointed out that some of the files are shambolic links. Given that this process is not idempotent (running it twice on the same file is bad), you had better generate a unique list of files in case one of the links points to a file that appears elsewhere in the list. Here is an example with `find`, though the code for a pre-existing list should be obvious.

```
$ find -L . -type f -exec realpath {} \; | sort -u | xargs -d '\n' perl ...
```

(Assumes none of your filenames contain a newline!)

Comment: some of the files are symlinks . How can we use the same solution ?

Comment: You first need to map the symlink names to the real filenames - this can be done with `realpath` from the `Cwd` module.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this

```
perl -pi -e 's/(timeouts\s*=\s*\{default\s*=\s*)([0-9.-]+)/print $1; $2*1000/e' *
```

Answer (score 0):

One suggestion for whichever solution above you decide to use - it may be worth it to think through how you could refactor to avoid having to modify all of these files for a change like this again.

- Do all of these scripts have similar functionality?
- Can you create a module that they would all use for shared subroutines?
- In the module, could you have a single line that would allow you to have a multiplier?

For me, anytime I need to make similar changes in more than one file, it's the perfect time to be [lazy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Larry_Wall#Virtues_of_a_programmer) to save myself time and maintenance issues later.